# What Layer of the OSI model would a hotspot operate on?

Tags: tcpip, hotspot

What layer of the OSI model would a hotspot operate on? I am seeing conflicting information, and I am unsure which is correct now. I have seen both Data Link layer as well as Physical layer, and I guess I can sort of make an argument for both. I even seen on one site it listed as layer 3, but I assume it was in error because I only seen this listed like this once. This is reminding me a little of the NIC and how it can be viewed as a layer 1/layer 2 situation. I am just hoping for guidance from more experienced minds than myself. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Pretty much all of them.  What is the point of your question?  If we understood why you needed an answer, it would be more likely we could give a reasonable answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I supposed that would help. I am studying networking, and I understand that things like Ethernet cables and routers would all be part of the Physical layer, and like I said earlier that it is arguable that the NIC can be considered in both layer 1 and layer 2, but I am seeing conflicting information as to where a hotspot operates.

Comment: I mean, frequently now, we access the internet wirelessly and we are less often having to use wired connections, so I was just curious as to where exactly that fits into the whole OSI seven-layer model. I can't see where it fits in all of them at all. I don't really have a point to my question other than curiousity. Is wireless still a networking question? Maybe my curiosity is getting the best of me? I tend to be curious by nature.

Comment: A hot spot that does not act as a router/NAT etc. would be a layer 1 & 2 device just like a physical NIC. If it can connect separate IP subnets or VLANs then it also includes layer 3. It won't operate on higher layers than that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I expect this depends on how you are defining hotspot.

If you are defining it in  its simplest possible incarnation - as a simple AP which allows open connections, then its operating on the Physical, Data Link layer.  This would be unrealistic.

In many cases, it will be deployed as a router of some sort, in which case its providing Physical, Data Link and Network layer - because it assigns an IP address, and routes onto the network.

If you are defining it as something which asks for confirmation through a web interface, I'd argue its using all layers initially, because its intercepting traffic

Comment: I do not understand how it can operate on all layers, though I am a novice, so I am not correcting you. I just do not understand and am looking for further explanation if that is possible.I definitely thought that it couldn't go beyond level 4, and even level 3 and 4 seemed to be packet filtering levels, so I was confused as to whether these levels were levels that could be involved in this type of operation, but I was seeing conflicting information, so I wasn't sure pertaining to level 3 pertaining to a hotspot. I just really appreciate any information you could share for my understanding.

Comment: Well, a hotspot will often have a webserver built in - so when someone connects to it it can intercept http traffic and show a login page. The web server is an application.   The interception of traffic to the web interface is done through packet filtering.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea. Now that makes sense. Thank you! See, now this is exactly why I am asking. I am looking for things that I do not know. I really appreciate the insight!

Comment: Why has this my answer been down voted?

Comment: Because I don't have a high enough reputation, it wouldn't let me vote persay, but I didn't realize that it would let me check an answer as my acceptance of an answer (I only thought I could vote, which it wouldn't let me do) I just checked my acceptance of your answer, so as far as I'm concerned you answered my question. To further on this, my professor stated almost exactly what you said, going one further to say it not only uses all layers but tends to hover in layer 7 (the application layer) (I had no idea) Thank you again! You are brilliant!

Comment: @Laura - Thank you - its relly good to know that your prof agrees with me and I have not actually gone mad yet.

Comment: We are all mad here lol

Answer (score 3):

A hot spot (access point) is "technically" a Data Link (layer 2) device. Every device that connects to it has a mac and the macs are stored in a list. When a connection is made and information is sent to them, they say "hey, thanks for the info, I'm going to check my mac table and then forward the frames out of the appropriate interface contingent upon referencing my mac table." It is not a layer 3 (Network Layer) because it doesn't hand out IPs or route conenctions based on IPs and their paths. They operate as a switch, but instead of link ethernet to ethernet, their responsibility is to bridge wireless traffic into ethernet traffic. (802.11 ->> 802.3)

Comment: This follows more what makes sense to me. Thank you for explaining it in a way that I have something to hang my hat on. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a pretty decent direct answer. The only way I could think it may be improved would be to add the steps on building the cam/Mac table. And that would have complicated the answer. +10 to you sir

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Internet is not modeled according to the OSI model so not all modern network appliances accurately correspond to a single layer in the OSI model, although it will probably be close to one or more.

Specifically, a wireless hotspot would be both layers 1 and 2. Specifically, the antennas and transceivers are the physical layer (layer 1), as they receive aerial signals and convert them to bytes (and vice versa). The other components are part of the link layer (layer 2), as they handle framing, MAC addressing etc.

A standard wireless hotspot is not part of the network layer (layer 3) or above since it is bridged to a wired, Ethernet network, and therefore belongs to a single routing domain.